# ProgressHUD: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: swift

I always get the same error using ProgressHUD.
Implementation is no problem but when I call `PRogressHUD.show`...

I get the error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

xCode version: 10.1

Swift version: 4.2

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add more information about your situation, things like Xcode version, Langauge (Objective-C/Swift), how did you install the module (Cocoapods vs manually) etc.
It will help other developers have a clearer Idea about your particular situation

Comment: xCode version 10.1, swift version 4.2, installed manually per drag and drop.

Comment: did you try to install it with cocoapods? it will make your life a lot easier... here is a [link](https://cocoapods.org/) in case you are not familiar with it

Comment: I did not try installing via cocoapods. How can I delete the existing .h,.m and bridging header file? Is deleting from my navigation controller enough?

Comment: 1) bridging header file should not have an `.m` file, only an `.h`, that's why it's called a bridging *HEADER*
2) you do not have to change anything with the bridging header, it works the same with Cocoapods, the bridging header bridges the Objective-C code to Swift, this process should still happen

Comment: Fixed: Installing over cocoapods was successful. Tahnks for your help!

Comment: Gladly!, if I add it as answer would you be willing to accept as the correct answer? it would help me a lot :)

Comment: and as a tip, in the future, try to be more specific when asking a question, the reason I was able to help was because I am familiar with the `ProgressHUD` Library in particular. it is usually helpful to include links, and a snippet of code displaying some context about your situation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the `ProgressHUD` [documentation](https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD), the recommended way install the library is through [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/)

> CocoaPods is the recommended way to add ProgressHUD to your project.

Now I don't know how exactly did you add the library to the project, but trying to install it with CocoaPods will most probably solve your issue.

The rest of your implementation should remain intact.